# check If one variable only out of many is greaten than another vairable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a scenero, i want a situation to check and return value FO
1.  IF ONLY ONE VARIABLE OUT OF THREE IS GREATER THAN ANOTHER VARIABLE
2. IF TWO OR MORE VARIABLE OUT OF THREE IS GREATER THAN ANOTHER VARIABLE

my code below

```
if(   $date1 and $date and $LatestMaintenancePcd ) > $today){
                       $indicator = 'success'; 
                    }
```

this only works for if all ther variables greater than today, but i want if one variable only is greater than today, also if two variable or more is greater than today

Comment: Then, do it step by step. `if($date1 > $today)`, `if($date2 > $today)` and `if($LatestMaintenancePcd > $today)`

Comment: Don't you get errors for that code?

Comment: *this only works for if all ther variables greater than today* - are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: Stick 'em in an array then `if(max($array)) > $today)`

Comment: @CD001, you are hitting something, please explain better

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you've put all the variables in an array then `max()` will return the highest value from that array; you can then compare that against `$today` - if it's false then **none** of your variables are `> $today`

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this? as you saied it if one is true it should get through.
 " || " - symbol stands for OR like $date1 > $today OR $date > $today

```
    if($date1 > $today || $date > $today || $LatestMaintenancePcd > $today){
        $indicator = 'success'; 
    }
```

then try this?

```
    $greater_dates = array();
    if($date1 > $today) { $greater_dates[] = 1; }
    if($date > $today) { $greater_dates[] = 1; }
    if($LatestMaintenancePcd > $today) { $greater_dates[] = 1; }
    if(count($greater_dates) == 1){
        $indicator = 'success'; 
    }
```

Comment: this wont work, i want something like if ONLY ONE  out of the three variable is greater than $today, please note...only one and not one more more